# Proper argument type for scalar JSON graphql

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, graphql, spring-webflux

What is proper input argument type for scalar JSON @Argument?

As the result I have all arguments in my map when I need only my:

[image]

My schema.graphqls

```
scalar JSON

 type Product {
   id: ID
   description: JSON!
   name: JSON!
   price: String
}

type Mutation {
   addProduct(description: JSON!, name: JSON!, price: String!): Product
}
```

I have controller with mutation:

```
@MutationMapping
fun addProduct(
    @Argument name: Map<String, String>,
    @Argument price: BigDecimal,
    @Argument description: Map<String, String>
): Mono<Product>
```

Mutation request:

```
mutation {
addProduct(
  description: { 
    en: "English", 
    uk: "Українська" 
}
name: {
  en: "English",
  uk: "Українська" 
}
price: "3.2"
) {
  id
  description
  name
  price
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found workaround:

Final version of mutation method:

```
@MutationMapping
fun addProduct(@Argument productInput: ProductCreateRequest): Mono<ProductResponseDTO> {
    return productService
        .save(productMapper.toProduct(productInput))
        .map(productMapper::toResponse)
}
```

As argument I use `ProjectedPayload` interface:

```
interface ProductCreateRequest {
    fun getName(): LinkedHashMap<String, String>?
    fun getDescription(): LinkedHashMap<String, String>?
    fun getPrice(): BigDecimal
}
```

So the result mutation request:

[image]